# Testing a callback function in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

Needless to say, the app is a lot more complicated that this, but the gist is the same. I cannot make major changes to the App, such as import/export the onSuccess function or changing to a class based component.

A button click kicks off the Login function, where I pass in an onSuccess function. I want to spy on the analyze function to make sure it is called, but in my test I have no way of calling the onSuccess function

Ideally I would like to do something like this:

```
test("analyze should be called", () => {
  let analyzeSpy = jest.spyOn(Analytics, "analyze");
  onSuccess() //<- cannot do this
  expect(analyzeSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Here is the app:

```
import Analytics from "./Analytics";

export function Login({ onLoginSuccess }) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("TIMEOUT OVER");
    onLoginSuccess();
  }, 2000);
}

function App() {
  function handleClick() {
    console.log("Login");
    Login({
      onLoginSuccess: onSuccess,
    });
  }
  function onSuccess() {
    console.log("Login success");
    Analytics.analyze();
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          handleClick();
        }}
      >
        Login
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is Analytics.js:

```
export default {
  analyze: () => {
    console.log("Analysis done");
  },
};
```

How can I test this?

Comment: What are you trying to unit test? You've included a few files, a couple components, and several functions? If you are wanting to test that `analyze` was called then you need to render `App` and simulate clicking the button to kick off the chain of callbacks. To be clear, this isn't a unit test, but more an integration test.

Comment: The Login() function has some dependencies that would require user intervention. Maybe I should mock the Login function.

Comment: if you're not, then you should probably use the `react-testing-library`, then you render the `App` component, `click` the button then you'll have your `onSuccess` called to see if the spy was called or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `render()` method of `react-dom` module to render your component into document provided by `js-dom`.

Use `document.querySelector('button')` to get the button dom, dispatch a mouse click event.

Use `jest.useFakeTimers()` to use fake versions of the standard timer functions(`setTimeout`).

After dispatching the click event, use `jest.advanceTimersByTime(2000)` to executes the macro task queue (tasks queued by `setTimeout`).

Then, make an assertion.

E.g.

`App.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Analytics from './Analytics';

export function Login({ onLoginSuccess }) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('TIMEOUT OVER');
    onLoginSuccess();
  }, 2000);
}

function App() {
  function handleClick() {
    console.log('Login');
    Login({
      onLoginSuccess: onSuccess,
    });
  }
  function onSuccess() {
    console.log('Login success');
    Analytics.analyze();
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          handleClick();
        }}
      >
        Login
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`App.test.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from 'react-dom';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import App from './App';
import Analytics from './Analytics';

describe('68400320', () => {
  let container = null;
  beforeEach(() => {
    // setup a DOM element as a render target
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    // cleanup on exiting
    unmountComponentAtNode(container);
    container.remove();
    container = null;
  });

  test('should pass', () => {
    const analyzeSpy = jest.spyOn(Analytics, 'analyze');
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    act(() => {
      render(<App />, container);
    });
    const button = document.querySelector('button');
    act(() => {
      button?.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true }));
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(2000);
    });
    expect(analyzeSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
PASS  examples/68400320/App.test.jsx (8.12 s)
  68400320
    ✓ should pass (52 ms)

  console.log
    Login

      at handleClick (examples/68400320/App.jsx:13:13)

  console.log
    TIMEOUT OVER

      at examples/68400320/App.jsx:6:13

  console.log
    Login success

      at onSuccess (examples/68400320/App.jsx:19:13)

  console.log
    Analysis done

      at Object.analyze (examples/68400320/Analytics.js:3:13)

--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File          | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files     |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 Analytics.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 App.jsx      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.666 s, estimated 10 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```